# Are there any deep learning models to forcast waveforms from waveforms?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I want to forcast waveforms from waveforms. Now I have collected the dataset.
The input feature is a waveform, e.g.:
[input feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYEDh.png)

The out is also a waveform, e.g.:
[output feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPsvG.png)

Are there any avaliable models to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

All sequence-to-sequence models will for this. If you want to do image to image translation, then, just convert your image into sequence using CNNs (see text recognition models).